# Save to DB after clear the push notification android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working with push notification and I have one problem.

When I click in the received notification my code launch a new intent with an activity.

I use:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DemoActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("msg",msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

ITS OK FOR ME

But if I want only save this notification in SQLite how can I pass the message?

I know that with:

```
        Intent bd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AbaseDatos.class);
        bd.putExtra("msg",msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntentbd = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                bd, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(contentIntentbd);
```

Call a new activity when clear the notification, but the new activity open the layout.

I dont want any new activity be launched. Its possible launch a javaclass with an Intent?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a service with an intent.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context%2C%20int%2C%20android.content.Intent%2C%20int)